# Web deployment task failed in Azure

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I am using Visual Studio 2022 to deploy a sample .net core 6.0 app to Azure. I have the Resource group and App service plan ready. I right clicked the project in VS and created a publish profile. There are no build errors. When I click publish, I get the following error.

Web deployment task failed. (The type initializer for 'Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentManager' threw an exception.)

Publish has encountered an error.
Build failed. Check the Output window for more details.

A diagnostic log has been written to the following location:
"C:\Users\PS\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp7641.tmp"

Content of this tmp file are as follows
System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> Microsoft.WebTools.Shared.Exceptions.WebToolsException: Build failed. Check the Output window for more details.
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
---> (Inner Exception #0) Microsoft.WebTools.Shared.Exceptions.WebToolsException: Build failed. Check the Output window for more details.<---

Microsoft.WebTools.Shared.Exceptions.WebToolsException: Build failed. Check the Output window for more details.

I have cleaned the solution, restarted VS, but that didnt help.

The error message is not very helpful. Can someone give some pointers? Thank you.

Comment: I'd add your comment below as an answer.

Comment: In my case, I was able to resolve this issue by closing VS, re-opening VS as Admin and running again (no idea if Admin was necessary)

Answer (score 1):

Just restart the VS2022 and create and deploy a new project...(probably some caching issue), I did it and was able to deploy as the step you see in the answer above

Answer (score -2):

I attempted to reproduce the problem, but everything worked well from my end by following the instructions below.
To begin, we installed [Visual Studio 2022 preview](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/visualstudio/visual-studio-2022-preview-4-is-now-available/) and other prerequisites for developing.net core 6  applications and other projects in our environment.

I tried to construct a sample .net core 6 app on my local machine and publish it to Azure under my resource group by creating an azure app service plan, however I didn't install any dependencies. It was successfully uploaded to Azure.

Here are steps for reference:
[image]

[image]

[image]

After successfully published to Azure output:

[image]

For more information please refer the [Visual studio 2022 preview release notes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/releases/2022/release-notes-preview)  & MS DOC for  [Deploy an ASP.NET web app to Azure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/quickstart-dotnetcore?tabs=net60&pivots=development-environment-vs)

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I found the answer here. Copy pasted - After talking to the team in Microsoft that owns this component I learned a simple solution:

Look for a key in the registry under the following paths that points the the problem assembly and delete it:

HKLM\Software\Microsoft\IIS Extensions\msdeploy\3\extensibility
HKLM\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\IIS Extensions\msdeploy\3\extensibility
(After cleaning up the registry, remember to restart Visual Studio)

Comment: thank you @bluepiranha, I would of never been able to figure this out.. deleting the registry key (well i just appended _old to the name) resolved the issue for me

Comment: @bluepiranha, excellent solution...that's the type of thing that drives me bonkers. an undescriptive error message in VS and nothing in the logs.