# In Visual Studio 2022, publish to IIS returns a build error, but publish to Folder is ok (and it was all working fine before)

Tags: c#, iis, msbuild, .net-6.0, visual-studio-2022

I've updated Visual Studio 2022 to 17.1.0 recently and I now have this weird error, but not on every project (on only one up to now).  I've tested other projects and they still work fine.

But this one project won't publish to IIS.  It builds/runs locally, it can publish to a Folder profile, and a previous version is working in IIS.

It's a .NET 6.0 web api project.

In the Output window I can see these 2 errors:

```
Error CTC1000: Method not found: 'Void Microsoft.VisualStudio.Containers.Tools.Shared.Functions.AzureFunctionsFeedDataProvider..ctor(Microsoft.VisualStudio.Containers.Tools.Common.Services.Logging.ILoggingService)'.
Error MSB4018: The "KillAppInsideContainer" task failed unexpectedly.
```

But I'm not deploying on Azure and I'm not deploying on a container.  The project was set up for Docker use but I commented out the `<DockerDefaultTargetOS>` part of the .csproj and excluded the `dockerfile` from the project to test if it impacted the resut; it removes the `KillAppInsideContainer` error but not the other one.

Any help appreciated!  Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To solve this publishing issue, I came back from *Microsoft.VisualStudio.Azure.Containers.Tools.Targets* version **1.14.0** to version **1.11.1** from nuget packages

Comment: Downgrading to 1.11.1 doesn't fully work for me. It removes the two initial errors, but then I get this instead:
"Web deployment task failed. (The type initializer for 'Microsoft.Web.Deployment.Tracing.WebDeployEventProvider' threw an exception.)".

There's now also a new 1.15.0 version since Feb 25th, but that yields the same error as the 1.14.0 version.

Update:
In all fairness, after deleting both the package and the Dockerfile (as I was doing an Azure AppService publish this time), it still fails with the latest error, so must be something else then.

Comment: FWIW, the last publish error I got, which seems to be unrelated to the Docker package as such, was resolved through this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69994724

Answer (score 3):

I suddenly had the same problem today and could get rid of it by upgrading Microsoft.VisualStudio.Azure.Containers.Tools.Targets from **1.14.0** to **1.15.1**.

Comment: It fixed it for me also. But only after I restarted Visual Studio.

Comment: Indeed, just restarting VS fixes the issue - until it breaks again after a while.

Answer (score 2):

```
Remove package Microsoft.VisualStudio.Containers.* || Microsoft.VisualStudio.azure.Containers.*
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: That did work indeed.  But since I can keep it to publish elsewhere in containers if I just move back from 1.14.0 to 1.11 I will accept the other answer.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

For what it's worth, this is what I had to do on my PC:

- In Visual Studio's "Tools" / "Options" menu, get to "Project and Solutions" / "Azure Funtions"
- Click on "Check for updates" and do updates if any
- Click on "Check for unused toolsets" and remove any unused toolset if any.

[image]